# Return value from efi application to efi shell

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I’m running an efi application from the startup.nsh in efi shell. How can I get a value as return of the application to the shell and use it in the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lasterror` variable, which contains the return value of the last program.

See more about scripting in chapter 4 of the [UEFI Shell Specification (2.2)](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf).